# Using Inconsolata in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

Anybody knows how to use the Inconsolata font in Visual studio 2010? While working nicely in Visual studio 2008, in 2010 it doesn't show up in the font selection box - presumably because it is not in TTF format...

Answer (score 7):

It seems that I've found more or less working solution:

http://dmitrimaximov.blogspot.com/2010/08/visual-studio-2010-vs-inconsolata-font.html

Comment: Anyone got this working satisfactorily? I've installed the original converted to TTF and the one from Google Fonts, but both won't let me change the font size.

Comment: I encountered the similar behavior. After VS restart the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: see Dmitry's comment below for updated links.

[Google's TTF offering of Inconsolata](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/inconsolata) ([tested revision](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/inconsolata?r=cd64a145f143cc4290efbdc112149f4a4b065c31)) appears in my VS2010 Fonts list and allows me to change sizes.

EDIT: See user1151080's comment below.

Comment: The link is outdated. Here is the correct one: http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/ofl/inconsolata

Also I've updated the test results for both VS 2010 & VS 2012: http://dmitrimaximov.blogspot.ru/2012/11/visual-studio-2010-2012-vs-inconsolata.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Since Google Code is closing down, here's an even newer-er link: https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/inconsolata