# Using Inconsolata in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, truetype

I use Inconsolata for VS2008, I want to use it for VS2010 as well, but VS2010 is not supporting open type fonts, so I converted Inconsolata from open type to true type. Now, I'm able to use the font in 2010 but it looks like a crappy version. Any thoughts on how I can use open type fonts in 2010 without converting to true type?

Thanks

Comment: Paraphrased: "I know VS2010 doesn't support open type fonts.  How do I get it to support open type fonts".  Post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Inconsolata in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306060/using-inconsolata-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://dmitrimaximov.blogspot.com/2010/08/visual-studio-2010-vs-inconsolata-font.html)´s a blog post to use Inconsolata in Visual Studio 2010, but there seems to be a problem how the converted Inconsolata is displayed.

Comment: yeah, I did that, it looks like a different font after conversion, nothing like original

Comment: submitted a bug to microsoft.connecy, bug#:686208